# Image zoomIn and ZoomOut when it is in scrollview and pagecontrol

Tags: iphone, ios

I preparing a images gallery,I want to ZoomIn and ZoomOut of images which are already in page control and Scroll view.Can anybody help me..
Regards..

Comment: Are you adding UIImageviews in UIScrollview?

Comment: Yes but I adding UIImageViews to UIView and then UIView to scroll,but now I have to add another scroll view to each image view for Zooming..But its not getting

Comment: then change the code as return yourview in which you are adding your imageviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set delegate for scrollview.Following code zoom your images.

```
-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)inScroll 
{
   return imageView;
}
```